# Sum of Left Child in a Binary Search Tree

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I have the following code which replaces each node in a Binary Search Tree with the sum of its children.

```
public static void sumofChild(Node root) {
    if (root == null) return;
    sumofChild(root.getLeft());
    sumofChild(root.getRight());
    if (root.getLeft() != null) {
        int sum = root.getData() + root.getLeft().getData();
        root.setData(sum);
    }
    if (root.getRight() != null) {
        int sum = root.getData() + root.getRight().getData();
        root.setData(sum);
    }
}
```

Now I wish to modify this code to update each node with only the sum of its left children.

So essentially if this is my input tree,

```
   12 
  9 14
7 10 13 17
```

The output tree needs to be,

```
    28
  16 27
7 10 13 17
```

I can't seem to get it right. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Why not just remove the getRight sum if statement?

Comment: I tried that, it wont work, because for internal nodes the right sum is a part of the left sum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void sumofChild(Node root) {
    if (root == null) return;
    sumofChild(root.getLeft());
    sumofChild(root.getRight());
    if (root.getLeft() != null) {
        int sum = root.getData() + root.getLeft().getData();
        root.setData(sum);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int sumOfLeftChildren(Node* root){
    if(!root) return 0;
    sumOfLeftChildren(root->right);
    return root->val += sumOfLeftChildren(root->left);
}
```